# Wants copyright information of OSS components

Tags: yocto

I want ot take copyright information of all open source components which are used for embedded system.Is there any short way to get the copyright information of OSS components?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018941/licenses-for-packagegroups-and-images-on-yocto) (given the "yocto" tag)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've got your `${TMPDIR}/deploy/licences` which has subdirectories for all recipes built. Those subdirectories inludes copies of both the license-files from those recipes, as well as the generic licenses for the declared licenses of those recipes.

There is also a subdirectory `<image-name>-DATETIME`, that includes eg a `license.manifest`, that lists all packages installed in the image, together with their licenses.

Answer (score 0):

That **very** much depends on your concrete setup; which of course you completely fail to describe here. How should we know which OSS components you are using in your embedded system?!

But the general answer is: there is **no** detour. When your product is using OSS components, and you want to "track" that; then you have to do the tracking work.

That means:

1. You have to create a catalog of **all** OSS components that are included in your product (and the version in use). Ideally, that would be no-op, because your build / library setup already makes such a distinction.
2. Then you use that catalog as input, to determine the **licence** for each and any of these components.
3. Finally, depending on the specific licence, you determine the effects of using OSS component X for your product.